# How can I update my Firebase data when my flutter app closes?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, backgroundworker

I want to update users time data after they finish using my app, and also I want to be able to update the data if they forcibly close the app too. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to run a code after or in closing app?

The code I want to run after closing the app is this:

```
endoff_time = DateTime.now();
var date = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(DateTime.now());
var startingTime = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(startup_time);
var endingTime = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(endoff_time);
database_Reference
    .child("users")
    .child(_wifiObject.macAddress)
    .child(date)
    .set({
  "name": userInformation[0].name,
  "router_bssid": userInformation[0].mac_ip,
  "date": date,enter code here
  "startingTime": startingTime,
  "endingTime": endingTime,
  "totalWorkTime": hours,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this, is using the [`onDisconnect()` callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works) in the realtime database sdk (!not firestore!). But the code would be on serverside with this solution...

Comment: you mean server side in java code and how can i retrieve the data from flutter to server side(java)